# Where is initialization taking place, in the init method or in the instance declaration?

Tags: swift, class, initialization

Please don't ask me to go read a link on the apple website, because I've read all of it!

Im confused on where the actual initialization of the property 'text' is taking place? Is it in the init method or is it happening in the instance declaration?

Because it seems to me that the initialization of the text property is happening in the instance declaration where it's being given the value "How about beets?"

And if so, then why does the apple book state that all properties must be initialized before an instance is created; within the class definition (correct me if I'm wrong)

Lastly if 'text' is actually being initialized in the class definition....where is the initialization??

```
class SurveyQuestion {

let text: String
var response: String?
init(text: String) {
    self.text = text
  }
func ask() {
    print(text)
   }
}
  let beetsQuestion = SurveyQuestion(text: "How about beets?")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initialization takes place in the `init` method. Note that `init` takes one parameter, `text`, and assigns that parameter to `self.text`.

Comment: so what value is initialized into the text property? All I'm seeing here is an empty variable assigned to self.text...??

Comment: Does that satisfy the initialization....setting an empty variable as the value of self.text??

Comment: @Ali: No, in `init`, `self.text = text` assigns the `text` parameter to `self.text`. `self.text` is never empty. It doesn't have a value when it is declared (in `let text: String`), but you can't use an object at all until it has been initialized, so `self.text` is never empty.

Comment: .....and the text parameter get its value from the instance declaration that sends in the value "How about beets?"........correct?

Comment: so technically, the class definition is not run until an instance of it is created......?

Comment: @Ali: Yes, basically. `let beetsQuestion = SurveyQuestion(text: "How about beets?")` constructs a new instance, which ultimately calls the `init` method.

Comment: @Ali: The class definition isn't really "run" at all. It's just a definition of the class.

Comment: ahh I seeeee.....well thanks a lot Ive been very confused but you my friend have just cleared up all that agonizing confusion, Thank you so much once again!!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the process followed in you code is:

1. You call `SurveyQuestion(text: "How about beets?")` to get an instance of the SurveyQuestion class.
2. When the class is running it's initialization method `init(text: String)` it initializes all the properties.  That means you're initializing the text property, giving it a value.
3. Finally the class finishes initialization and you get an instance of that class.

That corresponds to Apple's documentation as when you initialize the class the properties are initialized but you don't get the class instance until the init method has finished, and that means until all properties are initialized.

Sorry for the *initialization* redundance, I didn't find another way to explain it.
I hope that solves your doubts.